# JavaScript Array unshift() in an immutable way

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would you implement something like the Array `unshift()` method so that it creates a new array? Basically something like the Array `concat()` method but instead of placing the new item at the end, place it in the beginning.

Comment: push() adds it to the end. concat() can add to the start or end, depending on how you call it... you can always `origArr.slice().doSomethingMutative()` also...  `old.concat(newer)` vs `newer.concat(old)`

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.. EDIT: I meant to ask about unshift, sorry about that.

Comment: far from stupid, it's a decent question...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can actually accomplish this using the `.concat` method if you call it on an array of elements you want to put at the front of the new array.

**Working Example:**

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [0].concat(a);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Alternately, in ECMAScript 6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

**Working Example (requires modern browser):**

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = [0, ...a];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```